# Need sellable license-text for "commercial use" of GPL v3 software

Tags: licensing, gpl, commercial

I'm the creator of a software which is licensed under GPL v3. But now I want to sell the software for "commercial use" like Fancybox (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/#license).

I'm a real noob in licensing. So my question: Has anybody some good license-text examples which I can customize and use it as a digital product to sell (e.g. as PDF).

Comment: If you're asking about dual licensing with a normal commercial NON-FLOSS license then this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A license text is a legal document. As such, it is advisable that the text gets written by a qualified lawyer to ensure that the license actually says what you intend it to say.

I would strongly recommend that you ask a lawyer with knowledge of copyright law to draft the license for you.

Comment: No budget for a lawyer. I'm speaking for 9€ per license or something and low number of possible customers.

Comment: @rjgamer Not every business opportunity is worth pursuing. If you don't see any ROI after factoring in overhead costs like legal fees, why offer your product? Writing your own license may be possible, but is rather risky.